# How to change Spinner-Array in Android Studio?

Tags: android, spinner, adapter

i want to change the spinner-array of my Spinner2 by selecting something on my Spinner1.
It means if i change the selecteted item of spinner1 to position 2,3 etc. the listener has to change the whole items of my spinner2. (array in Strings.xml)
I tried to set it to another adapter but doesn't work...
Can anyone help me? thx
Here's my code:

```
public class DamenBH extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

Spinner spinner1;
Spinner spinner2;

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter65, adapter70, adapter75;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_damen_b_h);


    spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.beispiel1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
   
    spinner2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    adapter65 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.beispiel2, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter65.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter65);


    adapter70 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.beispiel3, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter70.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter75 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.beispiel4, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter75.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   



    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
   


}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter65);

      break;
        case 1:

            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter70);
            break;
        case 2:
            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter75);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this and it seems to work fine for me.

```
package com.example.energydrinkapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class EnterInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner manufacturer;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> manufacturerAdapter;

    Spinner flavor;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> flavorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_info);

        manufacturer = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_manufacturer);
        manufacturer.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        manufacturerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.manufacturer_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        manufacturerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        manufacturer.setAdapter(manufacturerAdapter);;

    }

    public void flavorArraySet(int flavors){
        flavor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_flavor);
        flavorAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, flavors, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        flavorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        flavor.setAdapter(flavorAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if (position == 0){
            Log.e("array","none");
        }

        else if (position == 1){
            Log.e("array", "monster");
            flavorArraySet(R.array.monster_array);
        }

        else if (position == 2){
            Log.e("array", "red bull");
            flavorArraySet(R.array.redbull_array);
        }

        else if (position == 3){
            Log.e("array", "reign");
            flavorArraySet(R.array.reign_array);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
```